# Parallel-ssh tunneling in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to set up tunnelling using parallel-ssh in python. here is a snip of my code. But I always get a connection error.

```
from pssh.pssh2_client import ParallelSSHClient

def net_command():
    hosts=['thost']
    client = ParallelSSHClient(hosts,proxy_host='jump',proxy_port=2222,proxy_password='1234',proxy_user='preet',user='preet',password='1234',
                               )
    output = client.run_command('df -h')
    client.join(output)
    for line in output['thost'].stdout:
        print line

net_command()
```

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pssh\ssh2_client.py", line 162, in _connect
    self.num_retries,)
ConnectionErrorException: ("Error connecting to host '%s:%s' - %s - retry %s/%s", 'jump', 2222, '[Error 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.', 3, 3)

Answer (score 0):

There may or may not be issues with your setup, but agent forwarding is not currently functional per [issue 286](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh/issues/286#issuecomment-796624263) on the parallal-ssh github.